# Execute only final command in nested list of groups in python click

Tags: python, python-click

I'm creating a deeply nested set of commands as click.group()s. I would like to ONLY execute the last group (command) input to the cli when I press the `Enter` key.

For instance:

```sh
cli sub_command subsub_command # < -- should only execute subsub_command
```

... should ONLY execute the last command `subsub_command`, however, it appears that click want's to execute the full stack of commands. (oddly it excludes `subsub_command`?):

```sh
$ cli sub-command subsub-command 
I am the root_command
I am sub_command
Usage: cli sub-command subsub-command [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
```

It also appears that it is running everything EXCEPT for the last command. Why is it displaying the help for `subsub_command` instead of simply executing it?

Here is my click code:

```py
import os
import sys

import click

@click.group(invoke_without_command=True)
def cli():
    print('I am the root_command')

@cli.group()
def sub_command(invoke_without_command=True):
    print('I am sub_command')

@sub_command.group()
def subsub_command(invoke_without_command=True):
    print('I am the subsub_command')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Any thoughts are helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using `@cli.group` over and over.

Commands are defined with `@cli.command`

So for example:

```py
import click


@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command(name='hello')
def hello():
    print('hello world!')
```

The idea of `@group` is to combine multiple commands together, the group method is used for defining a common context code for the entire group.

Comment: @orvelli - Thanks! yeah, I want to use the `click.group` simply as a hierarchy. This example doesn't show it, but I am generating these commands / groups dynamically, so I won't know ahead of time what is a leaf / command and what is a group. I had hoped that I could simply put in an arbitrary depth command and have it execute the command at that level. Basically a tree of executable `click.group`s. 


Any ideas?

Comment: What is the use-case of generating dynamic commands?

Comment: Anyway, you can always use `sys.argv[-1]` to get the last subcommand name. You will have to add a condition on each group to verify if you need to execute the code

Comment: looks like the `class Multicommand` has a `invoke_without_command`, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: The use-case is that I have an already generated, quite complex, tree of nodes in a custom object that I am passing in to generate the commands. Each node contains the kwargs and executable code. ultimately, I will be calling `mylib.execute(path="|cli|sub_command|subsub_command")` with that path being specified by the cli.

Comment: Well, one thing I notice is that using calling `cli sub_cmd subsub_cmd` won't even trigger the last code (because it is a group)

Comment: I guess you will have somehow to know if the command you are creating is a leaf or not

Comment: You can also implement it by using only `@cli.command`. by flatting everything to the root

Comment: thanks for the `argv` suggestion. Was right in front of me. It did the trick!  ... at least for the final token execution.